# Which is the right design to for MySql database: a column list or another table?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy. Basically I will have a bunch of posts like this.

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    post_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.user_id"), nullable=False) #author
    post_text = Column(VARCHAR(140), nullable=False)
    post_image = Column(VARCHAR(255))
    like = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    datetime = Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)
```

I want to keep track of users who have liked a post. I don't know if I should use a column list in the posts table or make another table altogether to save the liked user. Please give advice and keep it simple, I'm very new to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Like(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'likes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("posts.user_id"))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.user_id"))
```

And add following `likes` column to your Post and User classes respectively:

```
likes = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Like', backref='post')
likes = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Like', backref='user')
```

This two columns describes relationship between these tables, backref will add a reference to your Like class which will point to specific user and post.
Example of usage:

```
user = session.query(User).get(1)
post = session.query(Post).get(1)
like = Like(user=user, post=post)
session.add(like)
session.commit()
```

Let's say you want to get total likes of a post:

```
post = session.query(Post).get(postid)
post.likes.count()
```